# Get value using regex from string KP{{seq:2}}

Tags: c#, regex

See below example for more details,

Ex :

1. If I have string **`Demo19`** of pattern **`Demo{{seq:2}}`** (Where 2 is length of digits) then I should get output as **`19`**
2. **`Demo191`** of pattern **`Demo{{seq:3}}`** => Output: **`191`**
3. **`Demo19Test1`** of pattern**`Demo19Test{{seq:1}}`** => Output: **`1`** (Based on sequence)
4. **`Demo19KPTest1Demo`** of pattern**`Demo19KPTest{{seq:1}}Demo`** => Output: **`1`** (Based on sequence)

Demo,test,KP are just string

Comment: Your question is way too unclear: last occurrence where? What is a real life scenario? For the time being, it sounds like "I am trying to write a regex that will match `KP` substring that can be followed with one or more digits, and I only need to extract a fixed portion of these digits". If so, shA.t's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its as easy as the following pattern

```
(?<=KP)\d+\b
```

**The way to read this**

- `(?<=subpattern)` : *Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion. Continues matching only if subpattern matches on the left*.
- `\d` : *Matches any decimal digit.*
- `+` : *Matches previous element one or more times.*
- `\b` : *reduces backtracking.*

**Example**

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=KP)\d+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/879sPF/1

Comment: Simple i want to get {{seq:1}} number like 1 value @Michael Randall

Comment: Can you update your question with say 10 inputs and 10 outputs, everyone is confused.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I think this code can help you:

```
// This means you want to find `KP` followed by a fixed sequence of numbers
var pattern = @"KP(\d{" + seq + "})"; 
var result = Regex
            .Matches(txt, pattern)
            .OfType<Match>()
            .Select(c => int.Parse(c.Groups[1].Value))
            .ToList();
```

[**[ C# Demo ]**](http://rextester.com/JWC66673)
or

```
var result = Regex
            .Matches(txt, @"KP(\d+)")
            .OfType<Match>()
            .ToList()[seq - 1]
            .Groups[1].Value;
```

[**[ C# Demo ]**](http://rextester.com/EZN18647)